# File not found after Firebase/Firestore pod install

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, cocoapods

I am getting `grpc/support/port_platform.h file not found` error after I install pod `Firebase/Firestore` in pod file in current project.

[image: Screenshot 2019-05-09 at 4 45 52 PM]

Comment: Di you try to clean up and rebuild your project?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2973